# Hard time understanding javascript example

Tags: javascript

I am currently following a javascript course and am having issues understanding what is happening behind the scenes in javascript in one of the examples (see code below).

I understand most of the code and understand why the output logged is -> [false, true, true]. However there is one part which is driving me nuts (I pointed an arrow to it in the code at the bottom):

**my confusion revolves around the parameter `1`**:

what journey does the parameter `1` take from the moment it gets passed with `checkPastLimitSimplified(1)` in `var arr5 = mapForEach(arr1, checkPastLimitSimplified(1));`.

I understand that when `checkPastLimitSimplified(1)` is invoked an execution context is created for this function in which the parameter 1 is in the variable environment.

**But now what happens?** 
The function inside the `checkPastLimitSimplified` function is not executed yet but just returned. What does it look like when it is returned? at what point do the `limiter` variables receive the parameter `1`?

I understand that `.bind(this, limiter);` creates a copy of the function. Is its `limiter` variable already a 1 before it gets returned?

```js
function mapForEach(arr, fn) {

  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(
      fn(arr[i])
    )
  };

  return newArr;
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];

var checkPastLimitSimplified = function(limiter) { // < ----CONFUSED
  return function(limiter, item) {
    return item > limiter;
  }.bind(this, limiter);
};

var arr5 = mapForEach(arr1, checkPastLimitSimplified(1));
console.log(arr5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets rename variable to see relations:

```
var checkPastLimitSimplified = function(outer_limiter) {
  return function(limiter, item) {
    return item > limiter;
  }.bind(this, outer_limiter); 
};
```

`bind` modifies function signature to be just `function(item)` before return.
When client code will call `checkPastLimitSimplified(1)(item)`, limiter will substitute from binded context.

Comment: so if I understand this correctly, the parameter `outer_limiter` which gets passed into the function by calling `checkPastLimitSimplified(1)` is availble and resolved in .bind before the function is returned?
so essentially `function(1, item) {
    return item > limiter;
  }` is returned? so `return` does not stop .bind() from executing at this point?

Comment: Sure, `return` relates to whole `function(){}.bind()` expression.

Answer (score 0):

another way to make it more understandable is putting the inner function outside:

```
var checkPastLimit = function(limiter, item) {
    return item > limiter;
};

var checkPastLimitSimplified = function(outer_limiter) {
    return checkPastLimit.bind(this, outer_limiter); 
};
```

The result will be a copy of the first function with the first parameter (limiter) already defined.

This new function will need only the second param (item).

But there is no execution of the function code (the comparison with the limit) on this stage.